# « Aumône » (Bible Segond) : est-il courant ? « Don » interprète-il son sens propre ?

Tags: usage, synonymes, religion

D'après la Bible Segond (1910) :

> Lors donc que tu fais l’*aumône*, ne sonne pas de la trompette devant
>   toi, comme font les hypocrites dans les synagogues et dans les rues,
>   afin d’être glorifiés par les hommes. Mathieu 6.2

Il en de même dans la Nouvelle Édition de Genève :

> Donc, lorsque tu fais l’*aumône*, ne sonne pas de la trompette devant
>   toi, comme font les hypocrites dans les synagogues et dans les rues,
>   afin d’être glorifiés par les hommes.

En revanche, dans la version plus récente Segond 21 le mot « aumône » a été remplacé par don :

> Donc, lorsque tu fais un don à quelqu’un, ne sonne pas de la trompette
>   devant toi, comme le font les hypocrites dans les synagogues et dans
>   les rues afin de recevoir la gloire qui vient des hommes.

« Aumône » n'est-il pas courant ? Serait-il compris si l'on l'utilise ? Le mot « don » rend-il couramment le sens du mot « aumône », ce dernier signifiant *somme donnée par charité* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un don n'est pas une aumône; il y a un déplacement de l'idée initiale ; la différence entre le don et l'aumône est que ce que l'on donne lorsque l'on fait l'aumône est donné au vu d'une nécessité flagrante, une urgence et souvent à la suite d'une demande; le don est une attribution à quelqu'un ou à une organisation qui n'est aucunement en besoin de celui-ci pour maintenir sa position dans la société et qui ne demande rien mais qui par l'apport matériel de ce don est alors dans la possibilité de rendre sa position plus forte, de rendre son action plus efficace. Le don consiste aussi généralement d'un apport matériel beaucoup plus important pouvant aller jusqu'à des propriétés entières, des habitations par exemple; lorsque l'on parle d'aumône il ne s'agit, à part pour un peu d'argent qui peut être au plus de l'argent de poche, que de nourriture au plus  pour quelques jours ou de vêtements usagers et autres sortes de petites choses similaires.

On peut employer « don » à la place d'« aumône », cependant on perd les connotations du mot remplacé : il ne s'agit plus que de donner (simplement).

> (TLFi) A. Ce qu'on donne sans rien recevoir en retour.

On peut toujours utiliser « aumône » selon son acception habituelle. Cependant on peut vouloir mitiger son langage; dans le cas d'un ami dans le besoin, bien que le contexte soi le même, on ne voudra pas utiliser ce mot et on parlera plutôt d'aide et de dépannage ; la raison de cela est que les connotations d'infériorité de classe sociale et/ou de condition humaine inhérentes au mot « aumône », en sont indissociables ; en d'autres mots on ne fait l'aumône qu'à des êtres qui sont comparativement des déshérités.

Comment: Merci pour cette explication claire. Avez-vous une explication pourquoi dans la version plus récente l'on voit don et pas aumône même le premier ne peut interpréter la connotation du second ?

Comment: On pourrait faire l'évidente déduction qui découle de ce que je conçois comme étant la différence entre les deux termes mais je ne voudrais rien affirmer de cette sorte ; peut-être est-il bien le cas qu'une conscience religieuse nouvelle entrevoit la catégorisation que le terme semble presque indubitablement impliquer et que l'intention de le changer provient d'un élan de bénignité .